# Removing drop-down arrow from a Lookup Field on an Access form

Tags: ms-access-2010

I know this is a low level question, but I am "annoyed" that on my forms which are for read only purposes, i cannot figure out how to remove the drop down Arrow box on fields which are linked to a list of records..

Does anyone know if this can be done??

Comment: By "fields which are linked to a list of records" do you mean fields that have been defined as "Lookup Fields" in the table to which the form is bound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a Lookup Field in Access and in the Design View of a form you drag it from the field list onto a form you'll get a Combo Box control. Combo Boxes have the little drop-down arrow tacked onto the end.

To get rid of the drop-down arrow simply replace the Combo Box control with a Text Box control. That is, create a Text Box control on the form and set its `Control Source` property to the name of the lookup field, then delete the Combo Box control. The Text Box control will display the selected value(s) of the lookup field but will not allow you to edit them.

Answer (score 2):

There is an easier method than Gord Thompson's. This is in Access 2010 and may be applicable to other versions.  In either Design or Layout View, right click on the combo box control and go to "Change To" then select text box.